# How to separate file name and extension into variables on the commandline

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to copy a file x.dtsx from location a to location b.

If x.dtsx already exists in b then I need to rename x.dtsx to x_Standby.dtsx Then, after renaming copy x.dtsx to b

My current code looks like this:

```
if exists %1 rename %1 %(should be 1_standy.extension)
xcopy %1 %2
```

Comment: And I repeat: DOS is not CMD, and `[batch-processing] neq [batch=file]`

Answer (score 36):

If you use the Command Processor Extensions (which is default on Windows 2000 and later) then you can use the following optional syntax:

```
%~1         - expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~f1        - expands %1 to a fully qualified path name
%~d1        - expands %1 to a drive letter only
%~p1        - expands %1 to a path only
%~n1        - expands %1 to a file name only
%~x1        - expands %1 to a file extension only
%~s1        - expanded path contains short names only
%~a1        - expands %1 to file attributes
%~t1        - expands %1 to date/time of file
%~z1        - expands %1 to size of file
```

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

```
%~dp1       - expands %1 to a drive letter and path only
%~nx1       - expands %1 to a file name and extension only
```

So your command would look something like this:

```
if exist %2\%~nx1 ren %2\%~nx1 %~n1_standby%~x1
```